# Advice on HTML5 development framework for simulations?

Tags: javascript, html, game-development, animation

I am developing simulations for optometry to test students ability to use the examination equipment (refractors, retinoscopy, slit lamps etc) for a range of patient cases.

I am used to JavaScript, PHP, SQL, AJAX and jQuery.  Some C#.

I need the development framework to do the following:

All graphics scalable vectors - no problem expected there.

Interactive simulations of relatively simple equipment, like Trail Frames and inserting lenses, refractors etc.

**The Retinoscopy and Trial Frame Sim**

A trial frame I prepared earlier in Illustrator is attached as an example below.

The left and right sides of the frame under the horizontal bar need to move left and right via button presses above the knobs on each end of that bar (which are turned in real life to move the side frames left and right).  Those sides are comprised of several elements, call them sprites, in their own layers.

The circular parts will contain drop-in lenses that the user adds and removes to test the eyes.  Those parts (indicated by the circular scales) rotate by turning the knobs at the bottom of each side.  This would be button presses.  Again, the rotating elements are part of the left and right sides and in their own layers.

Then there are eyes for each patient case behind the lenses.

A slit beam is shone into the eye pupils which show different thickness and intensity and will rotate 360 degrees.  I don't see a problem there.  Some blending will be required for the light slit over the pupil.

**Database**

Users will need to login to the sim application and their results for each patient case are recorded in a database.  I assume I can use MySQL on my server for this.

A backend is needed to view student results and assign cases to students.  I see this as a separate part of the website and I don't see problems here as I have done this quite a bit.

**Questions**

What would people recommend for a development framework?

I like the idea of using either Adobe Animate (which I have) or Phaser and Phaser Editor (I have the latest version 3.32).  I also like the idea of just working in code and/or Phaser Editor, but mindful of the problems using Animate and creating movie clips and so on which just adds another level of problems.  I am avoiding ActionScript and anything Flash related.

I assume I can make a connection to MySQL database using either Phaser or in Animate using AJAX and PHP.

I have a major concern about layers and groups of sprites and being flexible in their movement on the screen.  So a tip on which framework to use in that regard would be appreciated!

[image]